# how to open an activity with url scheme android

Tags: android, url-scheme

I have two activities.

1.mainactivty.java

2.URL.java

now I would like to open second activity (URL.java) and I get `0` or `1` by using url scheme.

my manifest.xml :

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />    
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ex18_urlschme.URL"
        >

        <intent-filter >
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <data android:scheme="com.shadyab.shadyab"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

on a php page :

```
<button onclick="location.href='com.shadyab.shadyab:/status=0'">click me</button>
```

(after click on `click me`,I want to open URL.java and I get value of status. may be 0 or 1 ).

how can I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if(Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())){
            Uri uri = intent.getData();
            int status = Integer.parseInt(uri.getQueryParameter("status")); // reading status 
            Log.d("TAG","status code " +status);
        }

    }
```

Hope this helps!!